Unable to run Schemaspy due to SQL Server connection error due to trustServerCertificate
I get the following error when trying to run Schemaspy 6.2.4. I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2019. I don't know how to add the TrustServerCertificate=true setting. Can someone please help me with how to add this or have a list of all available SQL Server options to add to the configuration file? Thanks.

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: "encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ClientConnectionId:50cb97cb-80f9-4bb2-a455-71ddb94fa5b6

I tried this setting as a guess. I get the same result.
schemaspy.trustservercertificate=true


I was able to resolve this
https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/issues/566#issuecomment-501921905
I added to the command line
-connprops trustServerCertificate=true

you should put the comment into an answer so others can benefit from it
